# How to toggle multiple boolean divs

Tags: if-statement, jquery-animate, boolean, toggle, var

I have a grid of images and I'd like to toggle an animation when each image is clicked. This function sets x = true for all of the images, how do I ask it to just effect the img which has been clicked?

```
var x = false

$('img').click(function(){                  
if (x == false) {               
$(this).animate({border: '5px'});              
x = true;                             
}  

else {                
$(this).animate({border: '0px'});               
x = false;                        
}     
});
```

Thank you .
Here is the fiddle for the above : http://jsfiddle.net/m79fB/

Comment: You'll need to relate true or false with some attribute of the image tag , that is diffrent for all images . Where and how do you plan to use it ?

Comment: that jsfiddle demo illustrates the problem. When you click an image the border is toggled, yet when you click the image next to it, it takes two clicks to toggle the border on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery methods to addClass , removeClass and hasClass can be used here to easily solve the problem , 
CSS :

```
.add-border {
border:5px solid red;
}
```

Javascript/jquery :

```
$('img').click(function() {

var borderClass = $(this).hasClass('add-border') ; // returns true or false 

if(!borderClass)
$(this).addClass('add-border');
else
$(this).removeClass('add-border');


});
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hearsid/489hW/